# What should i use to do this task: Visualoforce or Lightning?

Tags: visualforce, lightning

I am starting  a new project next Monday, among the tasks assigned to me there  is one when i should create  a clickable map (an SVG map ).

There is two requirements in this task:

- the user can hover over different regions of the country and see (using a tool-tip or a modal) some real time relevant pieces of information (evidently, these data are retrieved from a the database).
- the user can click on any region to be redirected to another page for further processing and editing.

I am going to use a lot of JavaScript and redirection to get the job done and i have some doubts about the compatibility of lightning with these requirement.

My questions are:

- which environment is best suited to do that visualforce or lightning components knowing that the client use Lightning experience as his primary interface ?
- personally i prefer visualforce as it is a mature and complete product unlike lightning, are they any other risks that i am not aware of once the page is accessed from a lightning interface like (session Id and other parameters)?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Visualforce page if you will use a lot of Javascript. Soon, in Lightning will be much difficult use some important javascript feature, like the DOM manipulation due to this critical update "Enable Lightning LockerService Security". For more details, see [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/04/introducing-lockerservice-lightning-components.html)